# EF Core resolve with Data Annotation issue: unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property with Data Annotation

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on .NET Core + EF Core app.
There are my classes:

```
public class Container
{
        [InverseProperty("Container")]
        public v1_Case LegacyCaseDetails { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [InverseProperty("Client")]
        public List<v1_Case> ClientCases { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [InverseProperty("Source")]
        public List<v1_Case> SourceCases { get; set; }
}

public class v1_Case
{
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Container Client { get; set; }

        public int? SourceId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SourceId")]
        public Container Source { get; set; }

        public int ContainerId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ContainerId")]
        public Container Container { get; set; }
}
```

This code works fine and I have 2 questions:

1. Can I add `[NotMapped]` attribute on complex entity? Or there no sense to do that?

---

I have 3 relations into `v1_Case` with `Container`.

Into `Container` I need to use only `public v1_Case LegacyCaseDetails { get; set; }` but if I remove the rest 2 relations then during migration I have error:

`unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property v1_Case.Client ...`

2. What's the best approach to handle that situation above with using only Data Annotations (attributes)?

Comment: Where is the code? I see only model.

Comment: *Only data annotations* - Good luck. Aren't EFC limitations enough in order to put additional self restrictions? Many things in EF can *only* be done via fluent API, so not willing to use them is bad decision. What about `[NotMapped]`, it means *ignore this*, so apparently no other annotations, conventions or fluent configurations apply to it - for EFC it simply doesn't exist.